# How to fix 403 Forbidden nginx/1.16.1

Tags: laravel, nginx, debian, http-status-code-403

I am trying to run a Larevel project on this Nginx server. When I access project/public file via the web browser I get

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.16.1
```

Inside my public file, files look like this

[image: inside public folder]

How can I fix this?

PS: Just for the curiosity I renamed index.php file to index.html and accessed `project/public` via web browser. Then it shows me the code instead of giving 403 Error.

Here is the Nginx conf file.

```
user  daemon daemon;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";

pid        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/nginx.pid";

events {
    use                 epoll;
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept        on;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    access_log  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 80M;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types text/plain
               text/xml
               text/css
               text/javascript
               application/json
               application/javascript
               application/x-javascript
               application/ecmascript
               application/xml
               application/rss+xml
               application/atom+xml
               application/rdf+xml
               application/xml+rss
               application/xhtml+xml
               application/x-font-ttf
               application/x-font-opentype
               application/vnd.ms-fontobject
               image/svg+xml
               image/x-icon
               application/atom_xml;

    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types text/plain
               text/xml
               text/css
               text/javascript
               application/json
               application/javascript
               application/x-javascript
               application/ecmascript
               application/xml
               application/rss+xml
               application/atom+xml
               application/rdf+xml
               application/xml+rss
               application/xhtml+xml
               application/x-font-ttf
               application/x-font-opentype
               application/vnd.ms-fontobject
               image/svg+xml
               image/x-icon
               application/atom_xml;

    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf";

}
```

This is the nginx.conf.default file

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80

         location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: Please share your nginx configuration file

Comment: @ChristopheHubert is this located at etc/nginx? But there is no such a folder called Nginx in /etc. 
These is a Nginx config file in this location /opt/bitnami/nginx. I'll add it in the question.

Comment: @ChristopheHubert check, I added the nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring to pass .php files to Apache, then you're declaring to use a fastcgi service on 127.0.0.1:9000:

```
        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80

         location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```

First, you probably want to remove the Apache reference. Then you need to check your fastcgi backend configuration, as your nginx are "passing" all the php request to it.

You're declaring also `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;` and this mean that your php scripts are searched in /scripts folder. Is this right? If you want to keep your PHP files in html folder you nedd to change this line with `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $fastcgi_script_name;`. Check also what's inside file fastcgi_params, as this file is included and so you're loading pieces of configuration from it.

I suppose you're using php-fpm, I can suggest also to change the configuration in order to use a socket file instead of a TCP connection:

```
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

And change `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` with `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` in your php-fpm configuration.

Comment: this is my first time uploading a laravel project and i am using aws and getting the same error can you help me as well?        I have uploaded the application using beanstalk and it created a new instance and now i am facing this error